# Messaging system : One Postgre Database, several instances of the server

Tags: postgresql, cluster-computing

I am developing a messaging system (in java) that can support around 10k users. The architecture is supposed to be as following :
- 10k clients
- 2 or more replicas of the server (each on a different machine)
- 1 postgre DB

The application is aimed to run on a clustered environment (Amazone Webservice).

Now, I have read a couple of things on **Schemas** in Postgre DB's. I am not sure **if** I should use them (and in what way) or **if** a simple relational DB model will do.

Basically, the DB is supposed to be very simple (messages/metadata, queueID for messages, and users).

Thank you for your answers

Comment: 10k clients doesn't look like a lot of clients to me. Make everything just as simple as possible (as you always should do) and I guess you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with schemas. They are useful for semantically separating information in a database with lots of tables that can be grouped into clusters relevant to separate topics. They don't help you with performance, clustering or replicating databases. Also, I agree with Frank Heikens - unless each of your users sends messages with high frequency, I wouldn't worry.